# Android Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD.
Your CPU does not support VT-x.

Unfortunately, your computer does not support hardware accelerated virtualization.
Here are some of your options:
 1) Use a physical device for testing
 2) Develop on a Windows/OSX computer with an Intel processor that supports VT-x and NX
 3) Develop on a Linux computer that supports VT-x or SVM
 4) Use an Android Virtual Device based on an ARM system image
   (This is 10x slower than hardware accelerated virtualization)

Android Studio 2.1.2 x86

Comment: First check whether your _Motherboard_ supports virtualization. If yes, then you need to enable virtualization from **BIOS** settings and then download **HAXM** from SDK manager and install.

Comment: Please read trough the guidelines on how to ask a question in Stack overflow. 

As per your query: the error itself is giving you solutions and a simple google search would also give you viable results

Comment: As it is mentioned in the error _your computer does not support hardware accelerated virtualization_, it is not possible to run emulator in fast virtual mode. Instead use device for testing or upgrade your CPU.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Your CPU does not support VT-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39647841/android-your-cpu-does-not-support-vt-x)

Answer (score 0):

two possibility on your system
firstly check your system processor contain Intel Virtualization Technology
if your System is contain Intel Virtualization Technology then please enable virtualization technology

For More Info how to enable Intel Virtualization Technology

http://www.sysprobs.com/disable-enable-virtualization-technology-bios