# Android: Your CPU does not support VT-x

Tags: android, android-emulator, cpu, hyper-v

Your CPU does not support VT-x.
Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD.
Your CPU does not support VT-x.

Unfortunately, your computer does not support hardware accelerated virtualization.
Here are some of your options:
 1) Use a physical device for testing
 2) Develop on a Windows/OSX computer with an Intel processor that supports VT-x and NX
 3) Develop on a Linux computer that supports VT-x or SVM
 4) Use an Android Virtual Device based on an ARM system image
   (This is 10x slower than hardware accelerated virtualization)

What do I do to get around this limitation?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You try some of `your options`...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091677/intel-haxm-installation-error-this-computer-does-not-support-intel-virtualizat

Comment: Follow the link in previous comment and this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd-with-amd-processor there a lot of explanation there with screen shots of BIOS and other things.  There are more posts on the right pane, section called "Related". This topic has a good coverage.

Comment: This is clearly a duplicate of [Intel HAXM installation error - This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091677/intel-haxm-installation-error-this-computer-does-not-support-intel-virtualizat)

Comment: `AndroDid` is really nice typo :)

Answer (score 2):

According to [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html), to run an emulator the development system's CPU should support one of the following virtualization extensions technologies:

- Intel Virtualization Technology (VT, VT-x, vmx)
- AMD Virtualization (AMD-V, SVM) -- only supported for Linux

Your CPU is [Intel Pentium B940](https://ark.intel.com/products/55626/Intel-Pentium-Processor-B940-2M-Cache-2_00-GHz), which according to the manufacturer **does not** support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x). That's the reason for this error.

The workaround is to use an alternative Android Emulator, e.g. [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/).

Comment: Just an addition, BlueStacks also works as an Emulator and is currently running Android 7.1.1 (SDK 25). If you enable adb through BlueStacks Settings/Preferences, you can Logcat/Debug/Profile as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue with Mac M1 then just download Emulator provided by google and install it manually.

https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/12/android-emulator-apple-silicon-preview.html

Watch this youtube video for reference -
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mEKHrpV3LEQ

Answer (score 0):

### 2024 Up to date solution for apple M1 / M2 users

Android emulator is now **compatible** with arm processor out of the box.

But when you create a new emulator, **not all** emulator and system images in the list are `arm` compatible. Make sure you make the right choice (see screenshot above)

[image]